# split text to parts

Tags: c#, .net

I want to split this text in to 2 parts with C#.Net windows application.

```
C:\Users\Microsoft\Pictures\2010-04-22\003.jpg
```

First part: `C:\Users\Microsoft\Pictures\2010-04-22\`

Second part: `003.jpg`

Thanks.

Comment: @Everybody: Any comments on 'using Path vs FileInfo in this scenario'?

Comment: Using Reflector you can see that FileInfo.Directory name calls Path.GetDirectoryName(base.FullPath)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you are working with files and paths, use FileInfo:

```
System.IO.FileInfo fi = new System.IO.FileInfo(@"C:\Users\Microsoft\Pictures\2010-04-22\003.jpg
");
string dir = f.DirectoryName;
string file = f.Name;
```

Or, as Marcelo Cantos says, you can use System.IO.Path. Using Reflector you can see that FileInfo.Directory name calls Path.GetDirectoryName(base.FullPath) so it's very much the same

Answer (score 6):

Use the `System.IO.Path` class:

```
Path.GetDirectoryName(path);
Path.GetFileName(path);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var name = new FileInfo(@"C:\Users\Microsoft\Pictures\2010-04-22\003.jpg").Name;
```

Comment: you're only answering half the question